# Using Google Maps lib with Polymer

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm converting a Dart app that uses the GMap lib to Polymer. The map however does not seem to get rendered and nothing else of my app is as well. All I get is a blank screen. I'm not getting a runtime error.

The div where the map is rendered in is in a polymer element. In the Dart file, I'm instantiating the map like this:

```
final mapOptions = new MapOptions()
  ..zoom = 15
  ..center = LAT_LONG_KORTRIJK
  ..mapTypeId = MapTypeId.ROADMAP;
Element mapView = getShadowRoot("my-element").query("#mapView");
_map = js.retain(new GMap(mapView, mapOptions));
```

Any ideas on what be going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [js package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/js) does not support *Shadow DOM* for now. You are facing to [issue-99](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop/issues/99). Until a native Element support in `dart:js` lands I don't think this issue will be fixed.

**Danger Zone** : There could perhaps be a dirty way to work around this problem based on [this message](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web-ui/V66biNm0mi4/X9LzLzfNnqYJ) by manually replacing `/packages/js/` with the content of the pointed *js* branch.

Comment: Cool, I'll try it out. Seems like GitHub is down at the moment. I'll let you know how this goes.

Comment: Should I be able to add the js lib to pubspec.yaml referencing git? When I do so and run pub install, I get an error fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
e:\b\build\slave\dart-editor-win-trunk\build\dart\sdk\lib\_internal\pub\lib\src\git.dart

Comment: You can't use `pubspec.yaml` because `google_maps` claims for a `js` from _pub_ and there's [no way to override a dependency for now](http://dartbug.com/8566). That's why I say it's dirty because you have to manually replace a folder. Another way could be to retrieve `google_maps` locally, change its `pubspec.yaml` with the custom `js` and use a path dependency in your main app.

Comment: OK, I got it to work. I manually replaced the js package with the shadow-dom branch. Thanks!